# Rails - return last group (by date)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have some data that looks like this:

```
generated_at      code
1/7/17            aa
1/7/17            ua
1/7/17            tr
20/6/17           ua
20/6/17           gg
```

I want to create a scope that will return only the records from the maximum date.

I am thinking that I need to group by generated_at then get the max of that somehow but the logic is beyond me.

In the sample above I would want only the following returned:

```
1/7/17            aa
1/7/17            ua
1/7/17            tr
```

because 1/7/17 is the most recent date...

I hope I'm explaining this properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to find max date and query the date where generated_at equals the max date.

```
Data.where(generated_at: Data.maximum(:generated_at))
```

Comment: thanks - this does return the correct records but I was hoping to execute one query rather than 2 if possible and let the database server do the work :)